# Limiting actions under state events c#

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to create a screenManager that can open and close multiple screens at a time. I have bound the P key to open a screen called Pause when pressed. However, in a debug statement i can see that the screen is being created and opened multiple times with the press of the P key. I can stop this by checking if the screen variable is null or not before creating/adding it to the screen list. Then, though, I get a StackOverflow exception when trying to dispose of it. Her eis my code:

Pause.cs- If I dont call Dispose() here I am unable to reopen the screen in MainMenu because Pause is no longer null.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace RoomGame
{
    public class Screen : IDisposable
    {
        public ScreenController screenController;
        public bool isUpdating=true;
        public bool isDrawn=true;
        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        /*public Screen(ScreenController sc)
        {
            this.screenController = sc;
            this.isActive = true;
        }*/

        public virtual void Initialize()
        { }

        public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager c)
        { }


        public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        { }

        public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime,SpriteBatch sb)
        { }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Screen.cs - The StackOVerflow exception occurs in Dispose here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace RoomGame
{
    public class Screen : IDisposable
    {
        public ScreenController screenController;
        public bool isUpdating=true;
        public bool isDrawn=true;
        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        /*public Screen(ScreenController sc)
        {
            this.screenController = sc;
            this.isActive = true;
        }*/

        public virtual void Initialize()
        { }

        public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager c)
        { }


        public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        { }

        public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime,SpriteBatch sb)
        { }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

MainMenu.cs - This is the class that creates the Pause screen

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace RoomGame
{
    public class MainMenu : Screen
    {
        GameController gameController;
        ScreenController screenController;
        MyTexture start;
        Rectangle area;
        Vector2 position;
        ContentManager content;
        Screen pause = null;
        //public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        public MainMenu(GameController gc)
        {
            this.gameController = gc;
            gameController.Game.IsMouseVisible = true;
            //this.content = c;
            this.isUpdating = true;
            this.isDrawn = true;

            //this.graphics = this.gameController.game.graphics;
        }

        public override void LoadContent(ContentManager c)
        {

            position = new Vector2(100, 100);
            start = new MyTexture("Textures/Start",position,c);


            //texture = this.gameController.game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            //texture=this.gameController.content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            //texture = this.gameController.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
        }


        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //texture = this.gameController.content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");

            area = start.getBounds();

            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
            if ((mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) &&
            (area.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y)))
            {
                gameController.Game.Exit();
            }

            KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.P))
            {
                if (pause == null)
                {
                    pause = new Pause(this.gameController);
                    gameController.screenController.AddScreen(pause);
                }
            }

        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime,SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            start.Draw(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My mistake. The debug state was in the wrong place so while it was showing multiple adds the List.Contains statement was preventing it from acctually happening.

Comment: public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your code related to keypresses executes only once, store KeyboardState from previous frame and check it like this:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //everything else goes here

    if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.P))
    {
        //create a screen
    }

    oldState = key;
}
```